# how to make object and function interact in javasript

Tags: function, object

I was asked to make object with information of me and than make function using information from object but I have no idea how to make my object and function interact

Comment: You can pass the object as an argument to the function. Maybe have a look at some introductory material such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: `let me = { name: 'jim' }; function hello(you) { console.log('Hello '+you.name) } hello(me)` // Logs `Hello jim`